# What is the naming convention used in ScaLAPACK?

Tags: libraries, parallel-computing

I see that there are many files in the ScaLAPACK library without any immediately obvious naming convention... I'm sure that if the first letter is "p", it means parallel.  But I'm not sure how to make sense of the rest of the names as seen [here](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dir_78dd70a4654792622dd59c7dbd6a0c9f.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a number of the files in PBLAS, with some exceptions like `pilaenv()`, the stuff after the initial `p` follow a convention similar to BLAS. The second letter in particular determines if the routine handles `s`ingle, `d`ouble, `c`omplex, or double complex (`z`) types. The last portions are an effective shorthand for what the routine does, e.g. `axpy` for the operation $\alpha\mathbf x+\mathbf y$, or `ger` for the operation $\mathbf A+\alpha\mathbf x\mathbf y^\top$. [ScaLAPACK proper](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/explore-html/dir_35e25287b57dec2e0f537f7538ece03f.html) follows a similar convention; thus, `pdgetrf()` for example computes the LU decomposition (`getrf`) of a matrix with `d`ouble entries, and analogously for `psgetrf()`, `pcgetrf()`, and `pzgetrf()`.